# why do i get post id data when i am in homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I am trying to create a loop that will recognize the current post id and add a class to it in the menu bar.

this is the code I am using to get the post id value:

```
wp_reset_query();
$post = $wp_query->post;
$current_project = $post->ID;
echo $current_project;
```

this code is working, but the problem is that it also retrieves post id data when I am in the homepage with no posts displaying or queried. 
It shows the first post's id in order and adds a class to the post's link although it is not currently displayed.

how can I solve this?

Comment: You can add another condition, if(!is_home()){...}, in the if condition, do your all assigning things

Answer (score 0):

In WP Admin, have you set the homepage to a static page? If so then `$wp_query->post;` will be populated with post data. In your case the homepage will be a post of type 'page'.